# get transformed vertices positions after vertex shader in THREE.js

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am changing the positions of some vertices inside a vertex shader but i can't find a way to get those new updated vertices positions back inside js (i'm currently using THREE.js : the vertex position of my mesh's vertices  always remains the same).
I found this link [Retrieve Vertices Data in THREE.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053870/retrieve-vertices-data-in-three-js), but glGetTexImage doesn't exist in webgl (and i'm quite skeptical about this floating-point texture method as well).
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please include the code that you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If reading the data from the buffer is the only problem, you can do that like this:

```
//render the pass into the buffer
renderer.render( rttScene, rttCamera, rttTexture, true );

// ...


//allocate an array to take the data from the buffer
var width = rttTexture.width;
var height = rttTexture.height;
var pixels = new Uint8Array(4 * width * height); 


//get gl context bind buffers, read pixels
var gl = renderer.context; 
var framebuffer = rttTexture.__webglFramebuffer;
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);        
gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, width, height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
```

[WebGL - reading pixel data from render buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171932/webgl-reading-pixel-data-from-render-buffer)

But setting all this up is complicated, and reading the texture might be slow, why not do this on the cpu?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Even tho i didn't test reading the data from the buffer, i understood my approach was wrong (from all my searches everywhere i still wasn't very sure if i could have missed something about the gpu/cpu relationship). Anyway i accepted your answer.

Comment: @user3018088 What was wrong with your approach and how did you fix it?